# Setting up clientCredentials Endpoint Behaviour on WCF-Custom Send Adapter

Tags: certificate, client, biztalk, credentials, mmc

I am trying to wrap my head around how this should be set up correctly. I have two certificates, a client certificate and a service certificate. I've placed these in the MMC, on the service account for the host instance that handles the send port. So the client certificate is placed in the Personal folder and the service certificate is placed in the Trusted People folder.

I've tried using several "Find" methods to locate these certificates, such as thumbrprint and serial number, but I always get a "Certificate not found" exception back.

My current settings on the adapter.
Client certificate:

[image]

Service certificate:
[image]

My settings for Authentication:
[image]

SSL Certificate Authentication settings:
[image]

What is the correct way to add the certificates to the different stores, so that they can be located by Biztalk? I've found the MSDN documentation on the topic, but it doesn't really provide any answers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/clientcertificate-of-clientcredentials-element

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged in as the BizTalk Service Account to manage Certificates.  Run As doesn't typically work.

Other than that, the instructions should be correct.